# "I can be what this puzzle is in" (2nd of a riddle series)

Tags: riddle

> "I can be some amount of time,
>   and I can be what this puzzle is in.
>   But not only this puzzle.
>   I can be used to look at 'yourself',
>   when it's bright enough.
>   But that's usually not the purpose I was produced.
>   When I'm 'many', most of you use me.
>   In a more literal sense, I can contain 'fourteen'.
>   What am I?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are probably

> a **window**.

"I can be some amount of time,

> We refer to "windows of time", the brief period of time when a thing is possible to do.

and I can be what this puzzle is in.

> This puzzle appears in a browser window, for most of us.

But not only this puzzle.

> There are lots of other windows open on my desktop, for sure.

I can be used to look at 'yourself',
when it's bright enough.

> In bright enough backlighting, a (physical) window can show you your reflection.

But that's usually not the purpose I was produced.

> Windows were made to let light in and let you see out.

When I'm 'many', most of you use me.

> "Many" being "Window**s**" ... **[10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/b/windows)**, perhaps :)

In a more literal sense, I can contain 'fourteen'.

> OP notes 'fourteen' references the atomic number for Silicon, a component in glass.

Comment: I think I should make the third harder. Alright, just wait for it!

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> A quote?

I can be some amount of time,

> Quotation marks can be used for writing a time (like in *Usain Bolt ran the 100m in 9"58*)

and I can be what this puzzle is in.

> This puzzle is in a quote

But not only this puzzle.

> The tilte also is in quotes, and many things can be.

I can be used to look at 'yourself', when it's bright enough.

> ?

But that's usually not the purpose I was produced.

> ?

When I'm 'many', most of you use me.

> ?

In a more literal sense, I can contain 'fourteen'.

> 'fourteen' is contained by two quotes **'**